# Can I set up a PostGIS store/connection in GeoServer without user password for database?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, password

When creating a PostGIS store in GeoServer, the guidelines I saw ask us to fill in database connection parameters including:

*host, port, database, schema, username, and password*.

This is a bit problematic for my system because the PostgreSQL database is set up in a **passwordless** manner. Users can only connect to `localhost` using their user names **without** passwords. ***No password is needed or will be created for security purposes.***

When I tried to `Add Store` without giving the password (which does not exist), I got the following error.

[image]

In my case, the webservers, GeoServer and PostgreSQL/PostGIS are on the same machine . The `psql` client can connect to the server on `localhost` passwordlessly without a issue.

Is it possible to set up PostgreSQL and GeoServer in such a way that the GeoServer to PostgreSQL connection does not require passwords?

Comment: You can use a JNDI connection

Comment: I'm not sure if [pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) work with GeoServer, but it does for many other programs like psql, pgAdmin, ogr and others.

Comment: update: to answer my own suggestion, no [jdbc does not use pgpass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21074386/327026)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux you can probably use unix socket.
Then you need to have specified thu user name in the pg_hba file for local, with trust or pair as authentication.

Then when you connect you shall not give a host name at all. At least in other softwares that gives you a local connection over unix socket.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I just tried this, but got an error: `Field host is required` on the `New Vector Data Source` page for adding store. This is with GeoServer 2.8 under linux

Comment: Yes I guess you are right. I guess GeoServer is using jdbc which, according to this answer seems to not support local connection via unix socket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562471/connecting-to-local-instance-of-postgresql-with-jdbc

Comment: Host set to localhost and user set to the system username, leaving empty the password works here.